# Windows 10 IOT voice recognition

Tags: windows-iot, c#

Good evening,
I have been playing with the voice recognition in Windows 10 IOT core and C#. One thing I am having a issue with is keeping the recognition engine running. I have tried looking online and no samples seem to work.
I want the recognizer to stay active and never time out.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set your application as the default start up application (default application)

[image]

This way when your application crashes, it will automatically restart.